# Variables Dropdown menu in classic pipeline Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, pipeline

I have a YAML pipeline in Azure DevOps that contains a list of variables which I can choose which on of them to use in runtime.

This is my code:

[image]

And this is how it looks in runtime:

[image]

My question is how to create this option in a classic Azure pipeline?
From past threads I read I saw that there's no option to do that, but maybe something changed lately.

Comment: Hi asaf, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Can I make a few suggestions for improving your question? Firstly, pasting in your code is much better than linking to a screenshot. Secondly, your refer to "variables" but your yaml code is actually specifying **parameters**; I suggest you clarify which you are talking about.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately it isn't currently possible to do this in the classic UI

Comment: I would think this wont change as there is no new updates on classic release pipeline. wondering why you're moving from yaml to old classic pipeline ?

Answer (score 0):

Not Possible with Classic Release Pipeline.